# Multiple slug_field in SlugRelatedField Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In my Django application I am getting Json like this:

```
    "sales_order": 102, 
    "transport_by": 4,
```

I want to expand the `sales_order` and replace it with it's owner's `first_name` + `last_name`.
So I tried using slugrelated field but I am not sure how to get two values out of it.

Here's what I tried:

```
class AtableSOSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    owner = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field='first_name'+' '+'last_name')

    class Meta:
        model = MaterialRequest
        fields = "__all__"


class AtableFlowListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = AllotmentFlow
        fields = "__all__"


class AllotmentTableSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    flows = AtableFlowListSerializer(many=True)
    sales_order = AtableSOSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Allotment
        fields = "__all__"
```

But obvious error appeared:

> AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'first_name last_name'

How do I get the first_name + last_name in my JSON?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i had same problem as you :
in models.py add a proprety to your model then in your serializer make your slug_field is the proprety you created in your model.

```
@property
def full_name(self):
    return self.first_name+" "+self.last_name

owner = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field='full_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# feed model

    class FeedLike(CommonFields):
        feed = models.ForeignKey(Feed, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        like_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        users = models.ManyToManyField("users.User")


# serializer 
class FeedLikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    users = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, many=True, slug_field="full_name")
    class Meta:
        model = FeedLike
        fields = ["feed", "like_count", "users"]


# add function to relation model 
 @property
    def full_name(self):
        return self.field_nam
```